# Data from Three Tables

Tags: mysql

I want to pull data from three tables, but if the data doesn't exist in the 3rd table, the data from the two other tables should be pulled.

I have a query now:

```
SELECT m.name, m.zipcode, p.lat, p.lon, meta.meta_value
FROM members AS m
INNER JOIN zipcodes AS p ON m.zipcode = p.zipcode
INNER JOIN usermeta AS meta ON m.id = meta.id
WHERE m.zipcode = p.zipcode AND meta.meta_key = 'image' m.country = "USA"
```

`m.id` and `meta.id` don't exist for all of them.

For those who have `m.id`, "image" doesn't exist for all.

I want to pull the data from the 2 other tables independently of the existence of "image" and `m.id`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing the query to

```
SELECT m.name, m.zipcode, p.lat, p.lon, meta.meta_value
FROM members AS m
INNER JOIN zipcodes AS p ON m.zipcode = p.zipcode 
LEFT OUTER JOIN usermeta AS meta ON m.id = meta.id
WHERE m.zipcode = p.zipcode AND COALESCE(meta.meta_key,'image')='image' AND m.country = 'USA'
```

Comment: Thanks! Better, but still not correct! :-( I get about 218 rows of 313.

Comment: not correct? what rows are being left out? Try coalesce all columns in the where clause : 
WHERE COALESCE(meta.meta_key,'image')='image' AND COALESCE(m.country,'USA') = 'USA'  (note i removed m.zipcode=p.zipcode because already written in the ON clause)

Comment: Same output after that change! Can it has something to do with that not all users have an m.id that corresponds with the meta.id? Some users do only exist in the member table, but they're without this particular type of ID. If they don't have a member.id, then they also don't have a meta.id.

Comment: SELECT m.name, m.zipcode, p.lat, p.lon, meta.meta_value
FROM members AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN zipcodes AS p ON m.zipcode = p.zipcode 
LEFT OUTER JOIN usermeta AS meta ON m.id = meta.id
WHERE COALESCE(meta.meta_key,'image')='image' AND COALESCE(m.country,'USA') = 'USA'

Comment: Thank you! Seems to output the same as the previous. :-(

Comment: curious and curiouser.. how do you know there is suppose to be 313 rows? and all of the 313 rows has USA as the country?

Comment: This query gives me 305 (not 313) rows:

SELECT m.name, m.zipcode, p.lng, p.lat 
        FROM members AS m
        INNER JOIN zipcodes AS p ON m.zipcode = p.zipcode
        WHERE m.country = 'USA'

Answer (score 1):

You are using INNER JOINs; use OUTER JOINS to get NULL values in columns from joined tables where the condition is false.

For example:

```
SELECT m.name, m.zipcode, p.lat, p.lon, meta.meta_value
FROM members AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN zipcodes AS p ON m.zipcode = p.zipcode
LEFT OUTER JOIN usermeta AS meta ON m.id = meta.id
WHERE m.zipcode = p.zipcode AND meta.meta_key = 'image' m.country = "USA"
```

Comment: Thanks Julio, but this gives the exact same output as the query above!

Comment: @Helge I know but now you have NULL values so you can "play" with your WHERE condition expression to get your data eg `A IN (possible_val1, possible_val2, ..., NULL)`